# Does AES Incorporate SHA512 into its Algorithm?

Tags: security, sha, ase

Will aes256 be broken if the sha512 hash of the aes256 password is known?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if the SHA-512 hash of the AES-256 password is known

If an SHA-256 value of an encryption key is known, the encryption key is still hard (=impossible) to recover. Assuming the key is random enough and has no trivial values from the rainbow tables.

Edit:

> Does AES Incorporate SHA-512 into its Algorithm?

No, there are completely different things.

SHA-256 is used in PBKDF2 - it's a KDF (key derivate funtion) to generate an encryption key from a human password. The hash is used in form of HMAC-SHA2, so even the sha2 of the original password is known, it cannot be used to recover or compute the encryption key.

Comment: PBKDF2 formally allows _any_ PRF and v2.1 (RFC8018) _suggests_ HMAC of SHA-1 and all 6 SHA-2's, plus it is not the only key-deriviation function used, although until about a decade ago it was considered the best and widely recommended. However to emphasize: if the password is weak, _any_ hash of it, even a good slow one, can be broken.

Comment: This does not exactly answer the question. Extracting a key from SHA-512 due to user's bad password or any other means, doesn't break the AES. [AES is believed to be a PRP and it can achieve Ind-CPA or more](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/76738/18298). Accessing user password that generates the AES is not a break of AES!